# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tienda que despliega los productos y que al dar clic se tendría que abrir un modal mostrando los detalles de dicho producto.

Tengo varias librerias de JavaScript como jQuery, Prototype y script.aculo.us.

Antes funcionaba correctamente, sin embargo no se el motivo del porque ahora no funcione, lo único que se es que en la consola me sale el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined(…)
```

La composición de mis archivos es así, tengo la siguiente etiqueta que ejecuta la función show_window con un onclick de JavaScript:

```
<img src="<?echo($m_PRODUCTO['IMAGEN'] . "?SID=" . generateRandomString(20))?>" width="160" height="120" <?if($_SESSION['SES_SYSTEM']['B2C']['CLIENTE']['CLI_ID']){?> onclick="show_window('index.php?ACTION=APLICACION.B2C.OTROS.LOAD_ACTION&SUBACTION=DETALLE_PRODUCTO&PRODUCTO=<?echo($e_PRO_ID)?>', '&nbsp;', 590, 490);" style="cursor:pointer"<?}?>/>
```

La función show_window está de la siguiente manera:

```
function show_window(URL, TITULO, ANCHO, ALTO, PARENT)
{
  if(PARENT == undefined)
  {
    PARENT = 'LISTADO_PRODUCTOS';
  }

  windowDetalleProducto = new Window
  (
   'windowModal',
   {
     className: "modalWindow",
     title: "<FONT FACE='verdana' COLOR='#000000'>" + TITULO + "</FONT>",
     width: ANCHO,
     height: ALTO,
     top: 0,
     minimizable: false,
     maximizable: false,
     resizable: false,
     recenterAuto: false,
     showEffect: Element.show,
     hideEffect: Element.hide,
     parent: document.getElementById(PARENT)
    }
  );

  windowDetalleProducto.setHTMLContent("<div id='loading'><div class='cargando'><img src='./b2c/3pesos/img/estructura/loading.gif'><br>Cargando... Por favor espere</div></div>");
  windowDetalleProducto.showCenter(true, 60, 0);
  windowDetalleProducto.setDestroyOnClose();

  windowDetalleProducto.setAjaxContent(URL);
}
```

Y si sirve de algo, esto es lo que me arroja la consola de Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con `window.open` en lugar de `new Window`. `window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=400');`

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más explicito? @EdgarOrtegaRamírez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema.

El problema era que estaba utilizando diferentes frameworks de Javascript como jQuery, Prototype y script.aculo.us, ya que estas librerias suelen usar el alias $ y cuando esto sucede, puede surgir un conflicto o duplicidad de funciones.

Lo único que hice fue cambiar el alias $ en jQuery por j con [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) de la siguiente manera:

```
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();

  j(document).ready(function(){
    j('#myModal').modal('hide');

    j('#preventa').click(function(e){
      j('#myModal').modal('show');
      e.preventDefault();
      /*setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "index.php?ACTION=APLICACION.B2C.CATALOGO.GOTO_CATEGORY&OPC=1&CAT=1&ROW=32&SID=5a8evc7yfqUYdaEVlFTDVmbVFL4WHey4hkIl6abZ&PRECIO=37&TEMPLATE=3pesos";
      }, 5000);*/
    });

    j('button.close').click(function(){
      window.location.href = "index.php?ACTION=APLICACION.B2C.CATALOGO.GOTO_CATEGORY&OPC=1&CAT=1&PRECIO=68&TEMPLATE=3pesos";
    });

    j('#myModal .modal-content').click(function(){
      window.location.href = "index.php?ACTION=APLICACION.B2C.CATALOGO.GOTO_CATEGORY&OPC=1&CAT=1&PRECIO=68&TEMPLATE=3pesos";
    });
  });
```

De esta manera, el alias $ es sustituido por mi como j, y no tendré problemas con las demás librerías. Espero le pueda servir a alguien.

Comment: Buen trabajo! Además, muy bien explicada la respuesta. Seguro que será útil en un futuro :)